# Unity Editor script with multiple levels of selectable toolbars

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've created an editor script that shows a toolbar of different buttons along the top, the view changes depending on which toolbar button is selected. I'm currently using this line:

```
toolIndex = GUILayout.Toolbar (toolIndex, parsedTools, EditorStyles.toolbarButton );
```

but there are too many options that scroll off screen. How can I set it so it shows 10 buttons then shows the next 10 buttons underneath those, rather than all in one single line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I think `GUILayout.SelectionGrid` is what I am looking for…